# Custom 3D (parallel) FFTW transformation possible?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, fftw

I have a 3D array of real data that I'd like to transform with a either a DST or DCT along one axis and normal DFT's along the other two axes. The result should be a 3D complex array that holds this transformation's coefficients.

Do you know if the FFTW3 package offers such a routine - possibly in parallel - out of the box? FFTW3 provides such a routine for a simple 3D DFT in all three directions.

And if not, would you might have a hint on how to achieve it the best way in C/C++?

My naive idea: Assembly of DST/DCT followed by a 2D real-to-complex transformation along the first axis inside some wrapping routine. Then, one could think of a 1D decomposition to achieve the parallelism. A 2D would be nicer but much more work.

PS: 
This transformation is used in a spectral method for solving the Navier-Stokes equation.

Comment: Have you looked at [FFTPACK](http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/) (note that this is an old Fortran library, old enough that I think it was still FORTRAN....)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I did do so. However, FFTPACK is a little slower than FFTW. Also, FFTW offers all building blocks for the needed transformation already so it is just a matter of how to assemble it.

Comment: @DavidBowling What do you mean by old enough? http://www.2decomp.org/ , https://github.com/sdsc/p3dfft , ...

Comment: @VladimirF-- what I meant is that [FFTPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTPACK) dates from the days when Fortran was still called FORTRAN, i.e., before Fortran 90. It was just a joke... FFTPACK has been around a long time ;)

Comment: David Bowling,  I see. BTW @mrdy those libraries I linked provide better parallel decompositions than that one in FFTW. Also there is https://github.com/mpip/pfft/ which brings better parallel decompositions over FFTW.

Answer (score 0):

Your naive idea is the way to go. Individual dimensions can be transformed independently.

Comment: Yes, you are right and this fact is used by parallel implementations of FFTs. But I don't see how this helps with my issue.

Comment: I have built all of that for 3D complex in C++. I needed also float and double precisions. https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/ft/FFTWTraits.hpp
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/ft/DFT.hpp
But it is different from what you are interested as all 3 dimensions for me are complex. Do you have to go through many 3d volumes? 
In which case you could do the 1D ffts after eachother and the 2D ffts using openmp. or you use single threaded ffts in openmp loop. Careful: fftw_plan_init is not thread safe.